# Multiple Validation Rules and Validation Templates in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, templates, validationrules

Does anyone have a tactic for dealing with multiple validation rules and templates for those validation rules.

Example:

I want to have two validation rules (required & data)

I want either...

One template that can change is display depending on which rule is fired
or
Two templates, which get displayed depending on which rule is fired

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured out an approach that works and I was hoping to get feedback from anyone that might have an interest in this.

ValidationRule:

My validation rule is altered to send back an "ErrorObject" that has IsRequired & Message properties:

```cs
public class ErrorObject
{
    public bool IsRequired { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

// ...
    
return new ValidationResult(false, new ErrorObject() { IsRequired = true, Message = "Is Required" });
```

Template:

In the Validation Template I can now access these properties and alter the visual accordingly.  (In this example I'm showing an * for required fields)

```xml
<Border
    BorderBrush="Red"
    CornerRadius="3"
    BorderThickness="1">
    <AdornedElementPlaceholder
        x:Name="errorAdorner" />
</Border>
<TextBlock
    Text="*"
    Foreground="Red"
    Visibility="{Binding ElementName=errorAdorner,
                 Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem.ErrorContent.IsRequired,
                 Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
```

So this is a simple example, but you can imagine that this can get very powerful. Thanks to Microsoft for letting us send back an object!

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, not 100% sure, but I think you have to programmably apply templates if you want to display varying templates.

Is this approach similar to this? [Programmatically change validation rule in WPF TextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592919/programmatically-change-validation-rule-in-wpf-textbox)

Comment: I think you may be right about having to "programmably apply templates", but that is what I'm trying to avoid.  If I can just do it with XAML, then it becomes a thousand times easier to apply validation templates across the whole application.

Also, no the approach in that question you linked only refers to multiple validation rules being inserted depending on varying factors.  In my problem I can expect to have the validation rules in all cases, I just want to be able to act on them differently.

Thanks for the try though